# How can I make my shape "point" at my player

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to make a game where enemies spawn from the top (like a vertical scrolling game) and one kind of enemy will basically follow the player's X coordinate while going down. The enemy class is called Follower and right now it does points to the player (see update function on Follower) but it's not as accurate as I need it to be. For example, if the player accelerates, the follower won't be able to see him all the time.

One way to look at it is that I want the position of the player to be a coordinate in a radiant system and make the vertices of my Follower accurately just rotate and create a straight line looking at it every frame

here is the Follower Class:

```
public class Follower {

Player target; //follow this

//position
private Vector2 position;
private float x;
private float y;

//speed
private Vector2 velocity;
private float speed;
private float radians;
private float faceTarget;

//dimensions
private float[] shapeX;
private float[] shapeY;
private int numPoints; //vertices for the shape

private boolean remove; //to remove from the game

public Follower(float x,float y, Player target){
    this.target = target;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);

    numPoints = 4;
    speed = 200;

    shapeX = new float[numPoints];
    shapeY = new float[numPoints];
    radians = 3.1415f / 2;

    setShape();
}

public void setShape(){
    //top vertice
    shapeX[0] = x + MathUtils.cos(radians) * 30;
    shapeY[0] = y + MathUtils.sin(radians) * 30;

    //left vertice
    shapeX[1] = x + MathUtils.cos(radians - 4 * 3.1415f / 10) * 30;
    shapeY[1] = y + MathUtils.sin(radians - 4 * 3.1415f / 10) * 30;

    //bottom vertice
    shapeX[2] = x + MathUtils.cos(radians + 3.1415f) * 60;
    shapeY[2] = y + MathUtils.sin(radians + 3.1415f) * 60;

    //left vertice
    shapeX[3] = x + MathUtils.cos(radians + 4 * 3.1415f / 10) * 30;
    shapeY[3] = y + MathUtils.sin(radians + 4 * 3.1415f / 10) * 30;
}

public boolean shouldRemove() {
    return remove;
}

public void update(float dt) {
    float angle = (float) Math.atan2(target.getPosition().y - y, target.getPosition().x - x); //angle between the follower and target
    velocity.set((float) Math.cos(angle) * speed , -speed); //setting direction to follow the target

    radians +=  Math.cos(angle) * dt; //THIS HERE IS MAKING IT ROTATE

    x += velocity.x * dt;
    y += velocity.y * dt;

    setShape();

    if(y <= 0 - 60)
        remove = true;
    else
        remove = false;


}

public void draw(ShapeRenderer sp){
    sp.setColor(1, 1, 1 ,1);
    sp.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
    for(int i = 0, j = shapeX.length - 1;
        i < shapeX.length;
        j = i++) {

        sp.line(shapeX[i], shapeY[i], shapeX[j], shapeY[j]);

    }
    sp.end();
}

}
```

I am not adding the GameScreen because I do not see the need of showing how they are rendered, either way, it'll stay the same.

Also, with the line of code, I am using the Follower points to the player with the bottom vertice as the "eyes"

Thanks for the answers!